# Hooking CTRL pressed in GTK+ application

Tags: hook, gtk, ctrl

How can I hook CTRL pressed in "drawingarea_button_press_event_cb" function of GTK+ application?

```
void drawingarea_button_press_event_cb( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event )
{
 ........
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspect the `state` field of the `GdkEventButton` structure. It will have the `GDK_CONTROL_MASK` bit set if Control is being held down:

```
if(event->state & GDK_CONTROL_MASK)
  printf("You're totally in control!\n");
```